# Open and closed sets in an arbitrary metric space example

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have the following point lifted directly from my notes on open and closed sets in arbitrary metric spaces:

*"As an example of a set that is not open, consider $I=[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$, with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Then $1\in I$, but there is no $r\gt0$ such that $B_r(1)=(1-r,1+r)\subset I$.*

*[A point to ponder is this: If our metric is $(I,d)$, then $I$ is open.]"*

I completely understand the first part of the quote, my problem is with the second part. Have we not just shown that $(I,d)$ is an example of a set that is **not** open? How then is it that in $(I,d)$, $I$ is open? Is this a mistake?

Comment: In metric space $(\mathbb R,d)$ the set $[0,1]$ is not open. In metric space $([0,1],d)$ however the set $[0,1]$ is open. In that context $B_r(1)=(1-r,1]\subset[0,1]$ if $r>0$ is small enough. Btw, in any topology $(X,\tau)$ the whole space $X$ is open, i.e. is an element of $\tau$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a mistake. You have shown that $I$ is not open **in** the metric space $\mathbb R$ with the Euclidean metric. But if you view $I$ itself as a metric space (with basically the same metric), then it is a **different** metric space, and in it $I$ is open. Being open is a property of the set **inside** the ambient space, not of the set of itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not a mistake.

It is because $\ B_r(1)=(1-r,1]\ $ within the space $I=[0,1]\ $ (if $r<1$).

Note also that the *whole space* $X$ is always open in a metric space $(X,d)$.